# Blob data from Oracle to .zip file using python

Tags: python, sql

I have been trying to get the blob data from oracle into a zip file using Python. I couldn't find the answer on any of the other links. Below is the code:-

```
import cx_Oracle
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
con = cx_Oracle.connect("OPT", "OPT", "INDLIN1234:1521/OPTEPC1")
cursor = con.cursor()
sql_string = """SELECT F_name, F_released_data FROM epc_project where rownum<5"""
cursor.execute(sql_string)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
        blobdata= np.array(row[1].read())
        filename =str(row[0]) + ".zip"
con.close()
f = open(filename, "wb")
binary_format = bytearray(blobdata)
f.write(binary_format)
f.close()
```

Getting below error:-

```
   blobdata= np.array(row[1].read())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Please helpme out here

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Unfortunately your code is not quite ready for this site, since [we require that the code is working to the best of your knowledge](/help/on-topic). [so] might be a better place to look for help in your case. Be suce to check [their How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).